# Json API - Looking up deeper

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I have the following piece of code:

```
(json \ field.name).as[Int]
```

The problem is, the code seems to look only into the 1st "layer" of a json document, giving me an error when the JsObject is wrapped into an Array.

To better illustrate the point:

This json works:

```
{ 
  fieldName: 123 
}
```

This doesnt:

```
[ 
  { 
    fieldName: 123 
  } 
]
```

So, how do I look up the value of the fieldName in the 2nd json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, this json is an array where the first value is your object.

You can use [ordinal traversing](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsPath.scala#L168) to obtain the first object, and parse it.

```
scala> val json = Json.arr(Json.obj("value" -> 10))

scala> json(0)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"value":10}

scala> (json(0) \ "value").as[Int]
res1: Int = 10
```